# Derating of a Generator?

Tags: generator, power-engineering

What is actually meant by derating of a generator and what are the factors to be taken into considerations for derating a generator. Also what are the methods involved in derating a generator and what are the counter effects when derating is not done properly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term *derating* generally refers to over specifying a device or component in order to build in a certain level of tolerance or to increase the lifespan of the device.

Specifically, with a generator, you will have a finite amount of power it can produce.  When you approach that power limit the generator starts to labour more and more - like a car driving up a hill - and this puts extra strain on the generator and ultimately shortens its lifespan.

To derate it you would basically specify a more powerful generator than you need, so that when you are at your peak power consumption the generator isn't struggling.

There's no hard and fast rules about it, just what is easy and "available".

Say you have a peak power consumption of 9.8KW.  A 10KW generator would do, but only just.  Any unforeseen power consumption could have a critical effect, and during peak consumption the generator would be running pretty much at maximum.

Moving up to the next easily available generator, say a 12.5KW generator (whatever the shop has), would ease some of that burden and give you an extra margin for error.

Derating can also help to offset the unforeseen environmental changes, such as a heat wave, causing tolerances to become more critical, especially in heat producing equipment like a generator.

Answer (score 2):

> What is actually meant by derating of a generator?

"Derating" is where the nominal rating of equipment is reduced, to compensate for adverse operating conditions.

For most electrical equipment, power and current ratings are based on maximum component temperatures, i.e. amount of heat produced, and how fast that heat can be rejected to the atmosphere.

So any factor that increases temperature, or restricts cooling, tends to require a de-rating factor.

> What are the factors to be taken into considerations for derating a generator?

Generally, generators need to be de-rated if the ambient temperature is higher than some nominal temperature, i.e. 40° C. A de-rating graph, for a particular make of small gas-engine generator, is shown below.

[image]

Equipment may also need to be de-rated for high altitudes. Air density decreases with altitude, which reduces the cooling capacity of air, as well as the di-electric strength of air.

> Also what are the methods involved in derating a generator and what are the counter effects when derating is not done properly ?

Operating equipment past its rated capability is not recommended.

- The generator protection systems may detect that you are running the generator past its capabilites, and begin an automatic shutdown.
- Parts of the generator may run hotter than the design temperatures, causing accelerated aging of the asset.